# PHP, режимы работы и возможность чтения ошибок

Tags: php

Создаю пользователя в isp. Там есть чекбоксы

```
Может использовать PHP как модуль apache
Может использовать PHP в режиме CGI
Может использовать PHP в режиме FastCGI (Apache)
Может использовать PHP в режиме FastCGI (Nginx + PHP-FPM)
```

и далее

```
Тип обработчика php
не задан
CGI
FastCGI (Apache)
FastCGI (Nginx + PHP-FPM)

модуль Apache
```

Какой режим дает больше всего информации о ошибках, чтобы использовать его новичкам, пока они не изучили и не законспектировали глубже каждый из режимов? Никто не мог бы обменяться конспектом?

Comment: это не влияет на информацию об ошибках.

Comment: На вывод ошибок влияет не выбранный в isp режим работы, а настройки самого php

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.error-reporting.php